# Prove angles equality in trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a trapezoid and $AC, BD$ its diagonals. It is known that $\angle ADB \equiv \angle BCA$.

How can I prove that $\angle CAD \equiv \angle CBD$ ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

A proof (almost) *without words:*

> What can you tell about the triangles $\triangle AED$ and $\triangle BEC$ - where $\{E\}=AC\cap DB$ - knowing that 
>   $$\angle ADB=\angle ACB\; \text{ and }\; \angle DEA=\angle BEC$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hint:

Prove that $ABCD$ is cyclic.